# Get rows which doesn't have foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below query for getting data from PaymentsTable,

```
select `sales_payments`.*, `sales_invoices`.*, `customers`.*, `payment_options`.* 
from`sales_payments` 
inner join `sales_invoices` 
  on `sales_invoices`.`invoice_id` = `sales_payments`.`invoice_id` 
inner join `customers` 
  on `sales_invoices`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`customer_id` 
inner join `payment_options` 
  on `payment_options`.`paymentoption_id` = `sales_payments`.`paymentoption_id` 
where `payment_amount` is not null and `sales_payments`.`deleted_at` is null
```

this query returns only those rows which have `invoice_id` value, but I want those data well which doesn't have invoice_id or `invoice_id = NULL`

How can I get that?

Comment: Use a left join instead of an inner join.

Comment: a visual help for understanding joins https://lukaseder.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/venn-join1.png?w=700&h=381

Comment: If `invoice_id` is `NULL`, why would you want columns rom that table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, there are other entries that are related to another id that also need to pull in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` on all of your joins:

```sql
select `sales_payments`.*, `sales_invoices`.*, `customers`.*, `payment_options`.* 
from `sales_payments` 
left join `sales_invoices` 
  on `sales_invoices`.`invoice_id` = `sales_payments`.`invoice_id` 
left join `customers` 
  on `sales_invoices`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`customer_id` 
left join `payment_options` 
  on `payment_options`.`paymentoption_id` = `sales_payments`.`paymentoption_id` 
where `payment_amount` is not null and `sales_payments`.`deleted_at` is null
```